# Differential equations of a fluid-mechanical system

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-equations

I'm trying to simulate a real system, in order to do so I have modelled a physical system (fluid-mechanical) that behaves similarly with some simplifications. The physical model in question is as follows:

[image: Physical system]

The system consists on a piston with an orifice enclosed inside a chamber which is divided in two chambers due to the piston. Also, there are two pressure relieve valves that allow to regulate the force (pressure) exerted in each chamber, these valves are modelled with a spring and a damper, as the picture shows.

I want to obtain the differential equation of the system that allows me to know the position of the piston as function of time.

**Question:** how many differential equations will I need to simulate the model? I am not sure if I have to write an equation that includes the effects of the orifice, pressure relieve valves, etc. Or an X number of equations separately. In the latter case, how many (X) equations I need?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I have developed the equation for the piston. But anyways, I don't want to get the equations, just to know the number of equations I need. Because I am a little bit confused with the scope of the problem.

Comment: So, again.  Say in words or in equations what your thinking is so far.

Comment: I have one differential equation for the piston, one for each chamber (pressure) and nothing yet for the pressure relief valves. I don't know if I have to write an equation for each valve, or if I have to couple them into the pressure of the chamber equations. @ChesterMiller

Comment: This is not an easy system to model.  I would like to see what your equations look like, assuming that the relief valves are not present.  This was a good approach you used, by modeling the system in small bite-sized chunks (neglecting the relief valves).  As far as either of the relief valves is concerned, there is no flow unless the pressure difference across the valve is high than a certain amount.  Start out first by writing an inequality for that part.